the test coroutine is not completing with paging3 viewmodal unit test
I am getting following error, while testing view modal with paging 3,
Unit Test Link: https://github.com/TheReprator/ToDo/blob/main/appModules/searchToDo/src/test/kotlin/dev/uimodule/searchTodo/SearchTodoViewModelTest.kt

After waiting for 5s, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: [ScopeCoroutine{Active}@244440ed]
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 5s, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active

It's occurring due to use of 'coroutinescope use in asSnapshot()(convert flow paged data into list)', which is part of paging3 testing framework,
Google had introduced from the documentation(Paging3 asSnapshot) but hadn't provide any further information on it.
There are several other question related to it, but not able to sort or gather any data from there,
Link 1
Link 2
Link 3

What is your kotlin version?

@Hombre, 2.0.20
